# Recursive saving - throwing error

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I am writing a VBA script that recursively goes through and gets all the word and excel files from a directory then opens and saves them as templates then closes. Everything is working accordingly but when I attempt to close the opened excel application I am getting an error
"Run-time error '91':
Object variable or with block not set"

the code is as follows:

```
If ExtFind = "xlsx" Or ExtFind = "xls" Then
Debug.Print ("EXCEL FILE FOUND")
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.Workbooks.Open strFile
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=saveString, FileFormat:=xlTemplate
ActiveWorkbook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlApp = Nothing
End If
```

The error occurs on the line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=saveString, FileFormat:=xlTemplate
```

I am 100% certain that the variable saveString contains the correct value, which is being retrieved from an access table. The code executes as part of a loop. I think the issue is to do with the current workbook, but I am unsure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't believe I was so blind, all i needed to do was change:

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=saveString, FileFormat:=xlTemplate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

To:

xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=saveString, FileFormat:=xlTemplate
    xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close

Comment: Why open a new instance of Excel if you already have one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see by the comment that you noticed you must reference `Activeworkbook` as a property of the Excel application object.

However I want to suggest you consider doing it in a `With` block ...

```
With xlApp
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .Visible = True
    .Workbooks.Open strFile
    .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=saveString, _
        FileFormat:=xlTemplate
    .ActiveWorkbook.Close
    .Quit
End With
```

Comment: Good idea, will do. Cheers